# How to edit "MathJax equation" with jQuery-Tooltip or similar?

Tags: edit, mathjax, jquery-tooltip

How can I edit the text with a "tooltip" as in [this screencast](http://www.screencast.com/users/oerpub/folders/Jing/media/da0d8591-74d9-4d6f-ba40-81074f665356), please?

I would like to be able to the same with a "mathjax equation" (with Jquery or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but the screencast seems to be a demo of the Aloha-based wysiwhat editor which is [available on github](https://github.com/wysiwhat/Aloha-Editor), including a [live demo](http://wysiwhat.github.com/Aloha-Editor/cnx.html).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that demo on the website. There is http://wysiwhat.github.com/Aloha-Editor/src/demo/math/ but it's not working ("Loading Aloha editor..." take forever). 
I will look at the demo you pointed to me even if it's buggy: it worked the first time and after I edited an equation, all mathematical equations were not rendered correctly). Anyway a big thank you.